# Php mysqli connection remains after call procedure

Tags: php, stored-procedures, mysqli

I am trying to execute some queries in a mysql database using php's mysqli extension.

One of my queries is working well with string query, it fetches data and connection is closed (i am not sure how).

But when I try to call a stored procedure instead of using a string query, it works, but the connection remains on sleep state and doesn't close.

### Part 1

> working and connection closes

```
public function getCities(){
    $connection = $this ->db-> connect();
    $result = $connection -> query("select * from cities");

    return $result;
}
```

### Part2

> working but connection remains in sleep state

```
public function getCities(){
    $connection = $this ->db-> connect();
    $result = $connection -> query("Call procGetCities()");


    $isclosed=mysqli_close($connection);
    if(!isclosed){
        echo "notclosed";
    } else {
        echo "closed";//returnin closed
    }
    return $result;
}
```

I found the same question but it was unanswered.

Comment: When reading through your question after answering, i'm not 100% sure what are your concrete problem is.

Comment: I want to know why connection is closed using "select * from cities" but not closed when using stored procedure. And how can i close it.

Comment: Read my answer, you are misusing mysqli_close's return value

Comment: if it closes the connection it returns true right? and it is returning true in my situation but when i check my database from mysqlbenchmark i can see the connections on sleep.

Comment: Then next time, describe you checked mysql benchmark :) will look into it

Answer (score 1):

```
mysqli_close($connection);
```

Will return `true` if mysqli will successfully close the connection. So you are not checking if the connection is closed, but you are closing the connection with success.

> Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.close.php

---

Due to the information you added in the comments.

You are connecting twice to the database, but only closing the connection once. Normally you will store the connection in property and reuse the connection and then close it at the end of the calls or script. So something like this.

```
$connection = $this ->db-> connect();

public function getCities()
{
    $result = $connection -> query("select * from cities");

    return $result;
}

public function getCities()
{

    $result = $connection -> query("Call procGetCities()");

    return $result;
}

$isclosed=mysqli_close($connection);
if(!isclosed)
{
    echo "notclosed";
}
else
{
    echo "closed";//returnin closed
}
```

Comment: ty Martin but i need to know why connection is not closed when using stored procedure.

Comment: Why should it be closed?

Comment: because I don't need the connection anymore.

Comment: ty for your time but i want to know why when i use stored procedure connection remains in sleep. What is the difference between using sql command like "select * ..." in php code and using stored procedure.

Comment: Your problem is not that, you are opening two connections to the Server, but only closes 1, therefor you have 1 sleeping. Stored Procedures is just a collection of sql commands nothing more.

Comment: when i use stored procedure i am opening 2 connections and when i use "select * from cities" i am opening one connection?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95625/discussion-between-martin-henriksen-and-burak-karasoy).